# not able to load one user control at run time in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic, user-controls

I have got four different type of usercontorls in one page inside div 
one.ascx
two.ascx
three.ascx
four.ascx

like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/template.master" AutoEventWireup="true"CodeFile="ViewCertificateMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_ViewCertificateMaster" %>

<%@ Register Src="../Controls/one.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="one" %>
<%@ Register Src="../Controls/two.ascx" TagPrefix="uc2" TagName="two" %>
<%@ Register Src="../Controls/three.ascx" TagPrefix="uc3" TagName="three" %>
<%@ Register Src="../Controls/four.ascx" TagPrefix="uc4" TagName="four" %>

  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phBody" Runat="Server">    
        ...... 
        ............
         ............
          some controls(button and dropdown list)

     <table border="0">
     <tr>
       <td colspan="3">
            <div class="content_grid" style="border:0px solid black;width:100%;">
              <div style="width: 100%; visibility:hidden;" runat="server" id="divViewMyCerts">
              <uc1:one runat="server" ID="one" />
                            <uc2:two runat="server" ID="two" />
                        <uc3:three runat="server" ID="three" />
                        <uc4:four runat="server" ID="four" />

                  </div>
                </div>
            </td>
       </tr>
  </table>
```

and then in code behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        UserControl myAOSUsrControl = Page.LoadControl("../Controls/one.ascx") as UserControl;
        divViewMyCerts.Controls.Add(myAOSUsrControl);
        divViewMyCerts.Visible = true;
    }
 }
```

I am getting problem in the page load... I want load only one user control that is **(one.ascx)**

but I am able to see all user controls that is loaded and its taking huge amount of time to load the page because of four user controls are loaded at a  time ...

This is not what I want , I want only one user control to be loaded at the page load ...

how can I solve this problem to load only one user control at a time .....
would any one have any idea how to do this, that would be very great ful to me

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: you want to do this by code ?

Comment: yes I want it by code .......

Comment: In your UI already 4 user controls added. so no need to load it again. you can access it by id

Comment: I want to load user control only one at a time ....problem with these ones ....<uc1:one runat="server" ID="one" />
                            <uc2:two runat="server" ID="two" />
                        <uc3:three runat="server" ID="three" />
                        <uc4:four runat="server" ID="four" />

Comment: You're adding the controls both statically in the ascx and programatically in the code. The code in your page load method seem fine so why are you also registering the controls in the ascx?

Comment: that means you want to load one by one in page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to remove the four user controls from your page. also remove the visibility:hidden style you can add the attribute visible="false" to the div since you set it to true in your code. 
Then use the code you already have but remove the !IsPostBack

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/template.master" AutoEventWireup="true"CodeFile="ViewCertificateMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_ViewCertificateMaster" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phBody" Runat="Server">    
    ...... 
    ............
    ............
    some controls(button and dropdown list)

    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <div class="content_grid" style="border:0px solid black;width:100%;">
            <div style="width: 100%;" runat="server" id="divViewMyCerts">
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hi thanks one more problem is here I am getting error like this "Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request."

Comment: Do you still have this issue?